# AEM 6.4: Using wildcards in filter definition

Tags: wildcard, aem, aem-6

I'm facing following issue:

In one of my content project exists the file "filter.xml". It contains following entries:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workspaceFilter version="1.0">
    <filter root="/content/sites/de/produktpartner/a/rep:policy" mode="merge" />
    ...
   <filter root="/content/sites/de/produktpartner/z/rep:policy" mode="merge" />
</workspaceFilter>
```

My question is: To limit the entries in filter.xml can I use wildcards? If so, how?
I tried

```
<filter root="/content/sites/de/produktpartner/*/rep:policy" mode="merge" />
```

but it seemed not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root must be a path but you can further specify filters that allow regular expressions.

```
<filter root="/content/sites" mode="merge" />
    <include pattern="/content/sites/[a-z]{2}/produktpartner/(.*)/rep:policy"/>
</filter>
```

However, managing permissions using CRX packages can be very cumbersome. Check out [AEM Permission Management](https://github.com/Cognifide/APM)
It's a tool that supports a permission management DSL that makes the whole ordeal a lot easier. I work for the company that developed it and we use it on the vast majority of our projects.
The [Access Control Tool for Adobe Experience Manager](https://github.com/Netcentric/accesscontroltool) is another option that has worked for me in the past.

Comment: For a fresh set up of an AEM instance I have to add some policies programmatically. Though thanks for the link. I will try out your suggested tool.